# Which feature selection method to use for classification problem

Tags: chi-squared-test, feature-selection, spearman-rho

I have to do some feature selection for a classification problem with numeric features. I am not sure which feature selection method to use. Chisquared test or Spearmann's rank correlation coefficient, which one would be the best. Any suggestion guys?

Comment: Did you look at l1/l2 regularized Logistic Regression or SVM? The l1-norm essentially does feature selection.

Comment: Is your goal to worsen prediction?  Feature selection will assist.

Comment: Though this is not exactly related to Chi squared or correlation for variable selection, you may have a look here http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/72501/extract-important-features/172879#172879 I think a lot of questions here deal with feature selection...

Comment: Why do you "have to" select features? What is the goal of your larger project? How many data & how many features do you have? What do you mean by the chi-squared test or Spearman's rank correlation for feature selection here? I don't think a good answer can be provided without this information. Moreover, if you search the site & read some of the existing threads that relate to these topics, I suspect you will be able to learn what you need to know.

Answer (score 0):

Pearson's chi-squared test is for categorical data, so use rank. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goodness_of_fit

There are more feature selection algorithms than these. Check out this wikibook, it is for R but has a good list of routines.

http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Data_Mining_Algorithms_In_R/Dimensionality_Reduction/Feature_Selection

Answer (score 0):

If you are dealing with high-dimensional spaces, I'd recommend using an autoencoder to compress the dimensionality of the network then observing the receptive fields of the neurons. This will give some indication of which features contribute the most to the output in a non-linear fashion.